# Play alternative source for iPhone/iPad with mediaelement.js

Tags: html, streaming, mediaelement.js, wowza

I'm trying to use mediaelement.js to stream video files via a Wowza Server. Unfortunately I can only get it to work either on iPhone/iPad or in desktop browsers. I don't really know why this is, but I found out, that iPad/iPhone obviously needs a different URL to play the videos (http:// and playlist.m3u8).

This is what I got so far:

```html
<video poster="images/dummy.jpg" controls="controls" preload="none">
    <!-- source for desktop -->
    <source src="rtmp://tv.mysite.de/mp4:movieclip.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <!-- source for iPad/iPhone -->
    <source src="http://tv.mysite.de/mp4:movieclip.mp4/playlist.m3u8" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

```js
<script>
$('video').mediaelementplayer();
</script>
```

If I use this code, it only works in desktop browsers. When using the first source only, it doesn't work on iPhone/iPad. Same for desktop browsers if I use the second source.

Is there a way to make the magic happen for all devices/browsers? Maybe using the 2nd source as a fallback for mobile iOS or something or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no idea? :( I'm stuck in here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the iPad/iPhone source like this:

```
<source src="http://tv.mysite.de/mp4:movieclip.mp4/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! Unfortunately I just found out, that the movie doesn't start on Andoid. Is there another type-attribute that works for Android as well?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a path to the video that doesn't include a colon ":" ? I don't know if that's the issue, but the ":" colon is the special character for Mac File Systems, and is not permitted in a file path.